# Strange voltages in my office space

Tags: mains

On wanting to put on lamps I measured the conductors coming out of the ceiling - and they seemed a little off to me, so I wondered if anyone could tell me what it means.

I'm in Germany, and the conductors came in the newer color coded format brown-black-grey-blue-green.

Blue and green had no relative tension, as expected.

For the rest, look at the following table:

```
brown-blue   |  150 | 226
black-blue   |   65 |  94
grey-blue    |   34 |  48

grey-black   |   30 |  42
black-brown  |   49 |  75
brown-grey   |   77 | 120
```

The two columns are distinct measures for each of the settings of one of the light switches that appear to have had an influence on the voltages.

Bizarrely, I found no less than 4 light switches that had a significant impact (>20V) on the tension measurements.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @LeonHeller Yes, but were to put it? I had another question on mains asked on physics.stackexchange which was copied here.

Comment: @Leon: The question itself is rather basic and more for a electrician's forum, but without knowing it he's gotten into some non-obvious aspects of electronics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably measruing these voltages with a high impedance voltmeter.  That means even floating wires will have some voltage on them due to capacitive pickup.  Some of the light switches may actually switch some of these wires.  Others will just change the AC in the environment that is picked up by floating conductors.

To get a useful measurement, you have to put some load on whatever you are measuring voltage of.  Something like a 100 kΩ 1 W resistor accross the voltmeter when taking measurements should do it.  You may still get a few Volts from wires that are floating, but such readings should be low enough to tell you clearly there is no power available.

Comment: Adding to which : you can probably expect all the readings except Brown/Blue=226 to collapse under these circumstances. Black and Grey are the other 2 phases and would also read 230V (approx) if all 3 phases were in use.

Comment: It might be worth noting that some multimeters have a ["Low Z"](http://support.fluke.com/find-sales/Download/Asset/2718074_6116_ENG_A_W.PDF) setting intended for this sort of measurement.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I've got the wrong equipment to reliably measure this stuff. @RedGrittyBrick: I looked through the manual and it doesn't seem my meter can do that.

Comment: @John: Most ordinary multimeters don't have this low Z option, so it's no surprise yours doesn't. A meter specifically for electrician work is more likely to have it, and it might even be the default. However, you can get the same thing by putting a resistor accross a high Z meter as I mentioned in my answer.